# C++ Prevent Destructor call when emplace()'ing in map

Tags: c++, sockets, move, raii

I have a class which manages a resource (a network socket).

I have written a class `ConnectionHandler` which handles a network socket created from a call to `accept()`.

This class is designed with RAII in mind, when `accept()` is called, the returned socket is placed into a `ConnectionHandler`, when this goes out of scope the destructor closes the socket.

I'm also keeping track of all my open `ConnectionHandler`'s by saving them in a map (Maps the socket address (IP:Port) to the `ConnectionHandler` that corresponds to that address).

I'm having a problem "emplacing" these `ConnectionHandler`'s into the map though.

I've made it so that a `ConnectionHandler` can't be copied (at least I believe I've made it so), but when calling `std::map::emplace`, the `ConnectionHandler`'s destructor is called (presumably to delete a temporary object created somewhere along  the line) and the socket is closed.

As you can see, this creates a problem, because now the socket can't be used further down the program.

Is there any way for me to prevent the `ConnectionHandler`'s destructor being called when emplacing it into a `std::map`?

Here's the code for the `ConnectionHandler`:
Header file:

```
class ConnectionHandler
{
    private:
        constexpr static long BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 12;    // 4K Buffer

        SocketAddress peer;             // This is kept around to be able to produce clear exception messages when something goes wrong
        SocketFileDescriptor socket;    // using SocketFileDescriptor = int;

    public:
        ConnectionHandler() noexcept = delete;                                      // Default Constructor

        explicit ConnectionHandler(SocketFileDescriptor socket, const SocketAddress& socketAddress) noexcept;   // Value Constructor

        ConnectionHandler (ConnectionHandler&& handler) noexcept;                   // Move Constructor

        ConnectionHandler (const ConnectionHandler& handler) = delete;              // Delete Copy Constructor

        ConnectionHandler& operator= (ConnectionHandler&& handler) noexcept;        // Move Assignment Operator

        ConnectionHandler& operator= (const ConnectionHandler& handler) = delete;   // Delete Copy Assignment Operator

        ~ConnectionHandler();                                                       // Destructor

        void close() noexcept;                                                      // Allow the owner to manually close the socket if necessary

        void set_blocking (bool blocking) const;                                    // Make the socket either blocking or non-blocking

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ConnectionHandler& handler);   // Receive data from the socket

        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& stream, const ConnectionHandler& handler);   // Send data to the socket
};
```

And the implementation:

```
ConnectionHandler::ConnectionHandler(SocketFileDescriptor socket, const SocketAddress& socketAddress) noexcept: peer(socketAddress), socket(socket)
{
}

ConnectionHandler::ConnectionHandler(ConnectionHandler&& handler) noexcept: peer(std::move(handler.peer)), socket(handler.socket)
{
}

ConnectionHandler& ConnectionHandler::operator=(ConnectionHandler&& handler) noexcept
{
    this->peer = std::move(handler.peer);
    this->socket = handler.socket;
    return *this;
}

ConnectionHandler::~ConnectionHandler()
{
    if (this->socket > 0)   //  Check if the socket has been closed manually
                            //  Don't bother setting the socket to -1, the object is being destroyed anyway
    {
        std::cout << "Closing socket from destructor " << this->socket << std::endl;
        ::close(this->socket);
    }
}

void ConnectionHandler::close() noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Closing socket from close() " << this->socket << std::endl;   // Close the socket manually and indicate it is closed by setting it's value to -1
    ::close(this->socket);
    this->socket = -1;
}

[...]
```

This is what the SocketAddress class looks like (Doesn't work for IPv6, I'm aware):

```
class SocketAddress
{
    private:
        std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> ip;
        std::uint16_t port;

    public:
        friend void swap (SocketAddress& sa1, SocketAddress& sa2) noexcept;

        SocketAddress() noexcept;

        explicit SocketAddress(struct sockaddr_storage* sockaddrStorage);

        SocketAddress (const SocketAddress& address) = default;

        SocketAddress (SocketAddress&& address) noexcept = default;

        SocketAddress& operator= (SocketAddress address);

        friend bool operator< (const SocketAddress& lhs, const SocketAddress& rhs) noexcept;

        friend std::string to_string(const SocketAddress& address) noexcept;
};
```

And finally, here's the code that creates the ConnectionHandler and places it in a map:

```
void Server::listenLoop()   // acceptLoop() would be a better name
{

    struct sockaddr_storage remoteAddr;

    while(!stop)    // stop is a std::atomic<bool>
    {
        [...]   // accept() connections in a loop

        SocketAddress address = SocketAddress(&remoteAddr);
        this->incomingSockets.emplace(std::make_pair(address, ConnectionHandler(childFileDesc, address)));
    }

    [...]
}
```

This function runs on a thread separate from the main thread, the thread is kept in the Server object and is joined in the Server object's destructor.

Comment: Please note that zero is a valid filedescriptor, so in `~ConnectionHandler()`, use `if (socket != -1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your move constructor/assignment operator you need to invalidate the moved from objects. The destructors will still be called on the moved from objects. If their socket is not 0 then the destructor will still call close on the fd.

Comment: insted of the original, put «socket{std::exchange(handler.socket,-1)}» in mv ctor and «this->socket=std::exchange(handler.socket,-1)» in mv assign.

Answer (score 1):

Your move operations are broken as they leave you with two objects referencing the same socket. You need to put a dummy (invalid) socket value to the moved-from object, and check for that in the destructor.